# order of columns error when querying with DISTINCT

Tags: mysql

This works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id), 4 FROM table
```

this returns error:

```
SELECT 4, DISTINCT(id) FROM table
```

Error message:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'DISTINCT(id) FROM table' at line 1

Why?

Comment: what are you wanting to do for the `SELECT 4`? and is that a column name also?

Comment: the manual's syntax is pretty specific http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html - as it does not show that you can place anything before DISTINCT.

Comment: I'm selecting a constant value. Does it matter?

Comment: I believe it does as I stated in my second comment.

Comment: Distinct always comes after select like ....SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2....columnN
FROM   table_name;

Comment: Yes, it does. Distinct keyword comes before any field (constant value is also a field) because distinct applies to the entire resultset, not just to a single field.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it seems your comment should be an answer.

Comment: I'm guessing, but perhaps `SELECT DISTINCT(id),4 FROM table` is equivalent to `SELECT DISTINCT id,4 FROM table`. This suggests that if you really have a burning desire to use `DISTINCT` with parentheses, you could write `SELECT DISTINCT (4), id FROM table`.

Comment: @ZevSpitz The ordering would be different. `SELECT DISTINCT(id), 4` would place the `id` ordering first, as opposed to `SELECT DISTINCT (4), id` which would place the `id` ordering second. This will depend on which one Francisco would want, the `id` first or second(?).

Comment: @Fred-ii- The OP wants the `id` second. But my point is that the parentheses have no effect on the `DISTINCT` because `DISTINCT` is not a function.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I understand and that makes sense, given if that's what they really wanted, a valid point. This could also be about behaviour, given the added *"why"*. Your comments raised valid points; upvoted.

Comment: Thanks @ZevSpitz for noticing DISTINCT isn't a function so the parenthesis weren't needed. I think `SELECT DISTINCT 4, id FROM table` is the right syntax I have to use.

Comment: @FranciscoR Something to which I did make an edit to earlier in my answer, and have now made another slight edit, to the effect saying that *"with or without the brackets, produce(d) the same results".*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"@Fred-ii- it seems your comment should be an answer. – Francisco R"*

As requested by the OP:

The manuals' syntax are specific:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

As it does not show that you can place anything before DISTINCT.

SELECT:

```
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [MAX_STATEMENT_TIME = N]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
```

DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2, c3 FROM t1
WHERE c1 > const;
```

---

**Edit:**

[Zev Spitz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111794/zev-spitz) raised a few valid point in comments:

> *I'm guessing, but perhaps SELECT DISTINCT(id),4 FROM table is equivalent to SELECT DISTINCT id,4 FROM table. This suggests that if you really have a burning desire to use DISTINCT with parentheses, you could write SELECT DISTINCT (4), id FROM table.*

and

> *The OP wants the id second. But my point is that the parentheses have no effect on the DISTINCT because DISTINCT is not a function.*

In (my) response to this:

> *SELECT DISTINCT(id), 4 would place the id ordering first, as opposed to SELECT DISTINCT (4), id which would place the id ordering second.*

Therefore, if the query is to return the id (ordering) second, then the following query can be used to achieve this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (4), id FROM table
```

Differences:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id), 4 FROM table
```

[image]

Both following, produce the same results, with or without the brackets:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (4), id FROM table
```

and:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 4, id FROM table
```

[image]